OpenIddict password flow dont return claims
I am using OpenIddict Hollastin sample, but in client after authentication there are no added claims like Email, Name in Principal.
OpenIddictClientService.AuthenticateWithPasswordAsync

Claims exist in token itself
{
  "iss": "https://localhost:44313/",
  "exp": 1731397663,
  "iat": 1731394063,
  "aud": "resource_server_1",
  "scope": "offline_access",
  "jti": "d6369337-cf4f-4438-9f85-8fa54525e635",
  "sub": "889565e1-0f42-40f9-83dd-8898a95e51fe",
  "email": "***********@gmail.com",
  "name": "***********@gmail.com",
  "preferred_username": "***********@gmail.com",
  "debug": "test",
  "oi_au_id": "275e66f5-d1be-4bdf-a810-f076c557868c",
  "oi_tkn_id": "89da9c11-586d-4e44-8cca-0374ab0e53f1"
}

Only these two claims exist in principal
 "claims": [
        {
            "type": "as",
            "value": "https://localhost:44313/"
        },
        {
            "type": "oi_reg_id",
            "value": "cJPM2X1Glpq341zWEXCe6BuSO2fVrARkQAIXBQaftUk"
        }
    ]

Link to sample
https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Hollastin

Surprisingly all claims are parsed when i make request with token to API, just OpenIddictClientService authentication request dont return claims. Maybe claims in authentication response exist in other flows.
